# Pain points using Amazon CLI to deploy a python script in Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

My plan is simple, the following is my process:

OpenAWSCloudShell --> CreateFolder --> IntallPythonEnv+Packages -->zip --> UploadToAmazonS3 --> CreateLambdaLayer+S3ZipLink --> AddLayer
CreateLambdaFunction -->AddLayer

```
python3 -m venv [venv-name]
```

I noticed that the python environment in AWS CLI is only 3.7 (command above).And it always has issues for the package compatibility.

I have a very simple function to test in Amazon Lambda, the script only has two libraries, one is the yfinance and the other is pymysql. I downgraded all packages into the python3.7 environment and still, there is an error about task timed out.

```
Details
The area below shows the last 4 KB of the execution log.
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-02-19T16:35:14.042Z 0574b598-6e47-4e6c-b11a-a96b4db299da Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"
}
Summary

Init duration
1000.93 ms
Duration
3013.29 ms
Billed duration
3000 ms
Resources configured
128 MB
Max memory used
120 MB
```

Comment: Unclear what awscli has to do with this. The awscli ships with its own dedicated Python runtime. Your Python apps should not use this. BTW that Lambda error message after 3 seconds is typically an indication that your Lambda function exceeded the 3 second default timeout, either because it is simply running for too long or, more typically, that it has no network path to some resource that it's trying to reach.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to the Python version? Also Lambda supports Python versions 3.8 and 3.9 as well, you just need to specify the version https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html It's also unclear why you even mention the AWS CLI, as your error is a run-time error, not a deployment error. My first guess at the reason for your timeout is that the function is having trouble accessing your MySQL database.